# Prove that the number: $z = \det(A+B) \det(\overline A-\overline B)$ is purely imaginary.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem: Let $A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ be complex unitary matrices, where n is an odd number. Prove that the number:
$$z=\det(A+B) \det(\overline A-\overline B)$$ is purely imaginary.**

My idea:

We have that $AA^*=I$ and $BB^*=I$.

We also have that $\det A=\det A^*=(-1)^n \det A^*=-\det A$. Same for matrix $B$.

Am I free to say $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric matrices?

$$z=\det(A+B)\overline {\det(A-B)}$$
$$z=\det((A+B) {(A-B)^*)}$$
$$z=\det((A+B) {(A-B)^*)}$$
$$z=\det((A+B) {(A^*-B^*))}$$
$$z=\det((AA^*-AB^*+BA^*-BB^*)$$
$$z=\det((I-AB^*+BA^*-I)$$
$$z=\det((BA^*-AB^*)$$

This is where I am unsure of how to proceed. Am I free to say since matrices are unitary and skew-symmetric, their eigenvalues are purely imaginary thus $z$ must be as well? Is this statement correct?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(BA^*-AB^*)^*=AB^*-BA^*=-(BA^*-AB^*)$ thus its eigenvalues are purely imaginary. An the product of an odd number of purely imaginary is purely imaginary.

Comment: To make an argument that doesn't depend on eigenvalues: note that
$$
\overline{\det(BA^* - AB^*)} = \\
\det([BA^* - AB^*]^*) = \\
\det((-1)(BA^* - AB^*)) =\\
(-1)^n \det(BA^* - AB^*)
$$

Answer (score 1):

As proceeding along the lines given in the hint by @Tsermo , we find that $$ z = det(BA^{*} -AB^{*}) =\Pi_i^{n} e_i $$ where $e_i$ are the eigenvalues of $(BA^{*}-AB^{*}) $ which are purely imaginary(as the matrix$(BA^{*}-AB^{*}) $ is skew symmetric of odd order).Since n is odd therefore the result follows.
By the way how do you say that A and B are skew symmetric? In fact $det (A) = \frac{1}{det(A^{*})}$

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was unsure about the result so I combined some silly ideas from previous problems where similar conclusion was made when told $n$ is an odd number. Thank you.